# categorification and linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, category-theory

Vect is the category with objects as vectors and arrows as linear transformations between them.  Then these arrows have quite a bit of structure.  We can take the transpose, trace, determinant, eigenvectors, etc of them.  Do these operations make sense in other categories?  Is there a more general treatment of this I can read?

Comment: Trace, detrminant, eigenvectors make sense only for endmmorphisms (and not always for infinte dimensions), not general linear transformations. The transpose is related to the notion of dual space.

Comment: The operations you talk about aren't necessarily the things you want to generalize. I think googling about "Abelian Categories" and, once you're comfortable with abelian categories, "Tensor Categories" would be useful to you. I think, however, that the first generalization of Vect that you should read about (if you haven't already) is the category of modules over a ring. This is basically the concept of a vector space except now, instead of a base field, we just have a base ring. Surprisingly, this changes a great deal about the structure of the category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traces can be defined in monoidal categories: [arXiv:1010.4527](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.4527)

The transpose generalizes to morphisms between dualizable objects in monoidal categories. They are known as [mates](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/mate).

The determinant is the top exterior power, and the latter can be defined (for example) in Cauchy complete $\mathbb{Q}$-linear symmetric monoidal categories. A famous use is Deligne's [Catégories Tannakiennes](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-0-8176-4575-5_3).